# In journals submissions, what does "Confirmation of Intent" mean?

Tags: publications, journals, editors, special-issue

I am planning to submit a manuscript for a special issue in a journal. The guest editor puts a deadline for *Confirmation of Intent*. What does this mean? What the editor expects from the authors at this level? are there any samples of such thing?

Comment: The editor wants to know how many people are submitting for the special issue.  All you need to do is say you'll be submitting, and perhaps the approximate length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @vadim123 said in the comment, this is to estimate the size of the special issue. If it were too small, the journal may decide to:

- make a very small special issue;
- join special issues from two conferences into one;
- cancel the special issue and propose acceptance of the paper through a standard process.

If the special issue is too large, they would typically make it into a supplement.

**What should you do?** Reply *yes* or *no* for your participation in the special issue, and if yes, then the estimated length, like: *"We'll provide the full proofs while in the 10-page extended abstract there were obly sketches, it'll be circa 20 pages long."* If they wanted more information, they would have asked for it explicitly.